# Square root of $\sqrt{1-4\sqrt{3}i}$

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals

How can we find square root of the complex number 
$$\sqrt{1-4\sqrt{3}i}?$$

Now here if I assume square root to be $a+ib$ i.e.
$a+ib=\sqrt{\sqrt{1-4\sqrt{3}i}}$, then after squaring both sides, how to compare real and imaginary part?

Edit: I observed

$\sqrt{1-4\sqrt{3}i}=\sqrt{4-3-4\sqrt{3}i}=\sqrt{2^2+3i^2-4\sqrt{3}i}=\sqrt{(2-\sqrt{3}i)^2}$ which made calculation easier.

Comment: Square roots of numbers which are not positive reals are not well defined. For example, what's the square root of $-1$? Is it $i$ or $-i$?

Comment: @5xum That is true. However, we may still be able to get a coherent answer of the form $\pm(a + bi)$.

Comment: @5xum But we can still find square roots of complex number e.g. we can easily find square root of $2+i$ using the approach I stated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first find the square root of $1 - 4 \sqrt{3}i$ using the same method: let $(c+di)^2 = 1 - 4 \sqrt{3} i$ and then compare real and imaginary parts to find $c$ and $d$ explicitly. This will give you *two* different answers. Then assume $(a+bi)^2 = c + di$, and compare real and imaginary parts to find $a$ and $b$ explicitly. This gives you two solutions for both solutions of $(c+di)^2 = 1 - 4 \sqrt{3} i$, so in total, you get four different answers.

Answer (score 1):

*First step:*

Let $x+\mathrm i y$ a square root of $1-4\sqrt 3\mathrm i$ This means $\;x^2-y^2+2xy\mathrm i=1-4\sqrt 3\mathrm i$, whence
$$x^2-y^2=1,\quad xy=-2\sqrt 3.$$
Furthermore, $\lvert x+\mathrm i y\rvert^2=x^2+y^2=\lvert 1-4\sqrt 3\mathrm i \rvert=\sqrt{49}$.

So we have to solve the linear system (in $x^2$ and $y^2$):
$$\begin{cases}x^2-y^2=1,\\x^2+y^2=7\end{cases}\iff x^2= 4,\enspace y^2=3.$$

Thus, $x=\pm 2$, $y=\pm\sqrt3$. Finally, $xy$ is negative ($-2\sqrt3$), which implies the solutions are
$$x+\mathrm i y=\pm(2-\sqrt 3\mathrm i).$$

*Second step:*

Let $u+\mathrm iv$  a square root of $2-\sqrt 3\mathrm i$.  The same method leads to the system 
$$\begin{cases}u^2-v^2=2,\\2uv=-\sqrt 3,\\u^2+v^2=\sqrt 7.\end{cases}$$
We deduce $u^2=\dfrac{2+\sqrt 7}2$, $\;v^2=\dfrac{-2+\sqrt 7}2$, $\;uv<0$, so that the first two roots:
$$u+\mathrm iv=\color{red}{\pm\dfrac{\sqrt2}2\bigl(\sqrt{2+\sqrt 7}-\mathrm i\sqrt{-2+\sqrt 7}\bigr)}.$$

The other two roots correspond to $-(2-\sqrt 3\mathrm i)$:
$$u+\mathrm iv=\pm \mathrm i(2-\sqrt 3\mathrm i)=\color{red}{\pm\dfrac{\sqrt2}2\bigl(\sqrt{-2+\sqrt 7}+\mathrm i\sqrt{2+\sqrt 7}\bigr)}.$$

Comment: I think you misunderstood: OP wants to find the square roots of the square roots of $1-4\sqrt{3}i$, in other words the fourth roots.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi: I se. I'll complete my answer in a moment.

Comment: @Mathematics: Right. I'll update in a moment. Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{z}=\sqrt{\sqrt{1-4i\sqrt{3}}}=\left(\sqrt{1-4i\sqrt{3}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\left(\left(1-4i\sqrt{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=$$
$$\left(1-4i\sqrt{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}=\left(7e^{-\arctan\left(4\sqrt{3}\right)i}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}=\sqrt[4]{7}e^{-\frac{\arctan\left(4\sqrt{3}\right)i}{4}}$$

So:

$$\Re\left[\text{z}\right]=\Re\left[\sqrt[4]{7}e^{-\frac{\arctan\left(4\sqrt{3}\right)i}{4}}\right]=\sqrt[4]{7}\cos\left(-\frac{\arctan\left(4\sqrt{3}\right)}{4}\right)$$
$$\Im\left[\text{z}\right]=\Im\left[\sqrt[4]{7}e^{-\frac{\arctan\left(4\sqrt{3}\right)i}{4}}\right]=\sqrt[4]{7}\sin\left(-\frac{\arctan\left(4\sqrt{3}\right)}{4}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

First establish a formula for the square root:

$$(a+ib)^2=a^2-b^2+i2ab=x+iy$$ is equivalent to the system

$$a^2-b^2=x,\\2ab=y.$$

If we notice that $$(a^2-b^2)^2+(2ab)^2=(a^2+b^2)^2,$$ we have

$$a^2-b^2=x,\\
a^2+b^2=\pm\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$

The real solutions are

$$a=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}2},\\b=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x}2},$$
where the signs must be chosen so that $\text{sign}(a)\text{sign}(b)=\text{sign}(y)$.

---

Applying to the given case, $x=1,y=-4\sqrt3$, we find $a=\pm2,b=\mp\sqrt3$.

Then once again with $x=\pm2,y=\mp\sqrt3$, we get the final answer

$$a=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{7}+2}2},b=\mp\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{7}-2}2},$$ or
$$a=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{7}-2}2},b=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{7}+2}2}.$$

These four solutions form a square.

Answer (score -1):

The answer depends in part on the meaning that's ascribed to the square root symbol, $\sqrt{}$.  In almost all settings, $\sqrt a$ is taken to be positive if $a$ is a positive real number.  Assuming this to be the case, then the square root of the square root of $1-4\sqrt3i$ turns out to be one of the four number $z$, $zi$, $-z$, or $-zi$, where

$$z=\sqrt{{\sqrt7+2\over2}}-\sqrt{{\sqrt7-2\over2}}i$$

Exactly which one is meant depends on the **convention** you adopt for assigning an unambiguous value to $\sqrt{a+bi}$ if $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $b\not=0$.  (Most conventions set $\sqrt a=\sqrt{-a}i$ if $a$ is a negative real number. Note that $\sqrt7\gt2$, so all values inside square root symbols in the displayed equation are positive.)  Let me explain what I mean by this, and in the process show how the expression for $z$ was obtained.

**One convention** says that $\sqrt{}$ applied to a complex number with non-zero imaginary part has a *positive* real part. (This corresponds to assuming $-\pi\lt\theta\le\pi$ in the equation $\sqrt{e^{i\theta}}=e^{i\theta/2}.)$  Under that convention we have

$$\sqrt{1-4\sqrt3i}=2-\sqrt3i$$

so it remains to find real values $a$ and $b$ with $a\gt0$ such that $(a+bi)^2=2-\sqrt3i$, which is to say

$$a^2-b^2=2\qquad\text{and}\qquad2ab=-\sqrt3$$

Plugging $b=-\sqrt3/(2a)$ into $a^2-b^2=2$ leads to

$$4a^4-8a^2-3=0$$

which implies $a^2=(2\pm\sqrt7)/2$.  In order for $a$ to be real, we must have $a^2=(2+\sqrt7)/2$, hence

$$a=\sqrt{{\sqrt7+2\over2}}$$

The corresponding value for $b$ is most easily obtained by noting that $a^2-b^2=2$ implies $|b|=\sqrt{a^2-2}$ while $b=-\sqrt3/(2a)$ implies $b$ is negative, hence

$$b=-\sqrt{a^2-2}=-\sqrt{{\sqrt7+2\over2}-2}=-\sqrt{{\sqrt7-2\over2}}$$

which gives us the answer

$$\sqrt{\sqrt{1-4\sqrt3i}}=\sqrt{{\sqrt7+2\over2}}-\sqrt{{\sqrt7-2\over2}}i$$

**Another convention** says that $\sqrt{}$ applied to a complex number with non-zero imaginary part has a positive *imaginary* part. (This corresponds to assuming $0\le\theta\lt2\pi$ in the equation $\sqrt{e^{i\theta}}=e^{i\theta/2}$.)  Under this convention we have

$$\sqrt{1-4\sqrt3i}=-2+\sqrt3i$$

and, if you carry out the same reasoning as before, this time with  $a^2-b^2=-2$ and $2ab=\sqrt3$, you arrive at

$$\sqrt{\sqrt{1-4\sqrt3i}}=\sqrt{{\sqrt7-2\over2}}+\sqrt{{\sqrt7+2\over2}}i$$

which can be recognized as $zi$.  (We can check that we have the correct signs by noting that $2ab=\sqrt3$ implies $a$ must have the same sign as $b$, which the convention requires to be positive.)

**A final remark**:  My thanks to Wojowu, who pointed out an egregious mistake in my original answer.  (I thought the number in question was $\sqrt{1-4\sqrt3}i$ rather than $\sqrt{1-4\sqrt3i}$, which, if you can see the difference, makes a world of difference.)

Comment: The $i$ in OP's number is under the square root sign as well.

Comment: @Wojowu, you're quite right.  I thought I had checked carefully, but clearly I hadn't.  Please ping me once you've seen this mea culpa, and I'll delete the answer.

Comment: Thanks for waiting and letting me see this comment of yours :)

Comment: @Wojowu, I've redone my answer completely.  Thank you again for pointing out the error in the original.